# Different canvas sizes when using drawImage(canvas,0,0)

Tags: html, canvas, height, html5-canvas

I have 2 canvas elements these getting its height from a parent div.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var canvas2 = document.getElementById("canvas2");
canvas.width = canvas.width;
canvas.height = canvas.height;
canvas2.width = canvas2.width;
canvas2.height = canvas2.height;
```

The sizes of the canvas elements are correct in the DOM. Now i get a Problem with the drawImage() function.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var canvas2 = document.getElementById("canvas2");
var ctx2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");
for(var i = 0;i<len;i++){ 
  !magic drawings!
}
ctx2.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);
```

The Problem is it copy the first canvas to the canvas2. When the first canvas is 150px height it only applies 150px of canvas drawing on the second canvas which is 200px height.

Any Idea or suggestion?

**Edit**

Ok one possible solution, but its not pretty.

```
ctx2.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, canvas2.width, canvas2.height);
```

So the canvas gets resized. Because the width doesn't change it gets stretched regarding to the higher height. so not a perfect solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the scaling parameters of canvas context to avoid stretching

```
var scaleFactor=canvas2.height/canvas.height;

ctx2.drawImage(canvas,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height,
                      0,0,canvas.width*scaleFactor,canvas.height*scaleFactor);
```

Comment: made an edit to your post, because the width of 2 elements is the same width. This worked, thanks.